# Pylint: 'Unable to import 'pathlib' (import-error)'

Tags: python, pylint

Why does pylint say it can import builtin modules? My code executes without error and in python.exe I can load any builtin or pip installed module.

```
PS F:\z0py> python.exe -m pylint .\jake9wi_file_hashing\
************* Module jake9wi_file_hashing.funcs
jake9wi_file_hashing\funcs.py:3:0: E0401: Unable to import 'pathlib' (import-error)
jake9wi_file_hashing\funcs.py:4:0: E0401: Unable to import 'hashlib' (import-error)
jake9wi_file_hashing\funcs.py:5:0: E0401: Unable to import 'json' (import-error)
************* Module jake9wi_file_hashing.__main__
jake9wi_file_hashing\__main__.py:2:0: E0401: Unable to import 'os' (import-error)
jake9wi_file_hashing\__main__.py:4:0: E0401: Unable to import 'pathlib' (import-error)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 7.13/10 (previous run: 7.05/10, +0.08)
```

Comment: I have the same problem and it seem to be cause by running pylint form a embeded Python (a .zip from "Windows embeddable package"). Is it your case too?